# Python: How do I get the word count from a specific line of text and save it to do calculations on it

Tags: python

I am trying to count the number of words in a file and then I want to do some calculations of those numbers. Right now, this code will only save the last line of code. How can I get this to work?

```
def fileVerify():
    start = 0
    while start == 0:
        fileName = input("Please enter the name of the file you want to open ")
        try:
            inFile = open(fileName, "r")
            inFile.close()
            start = 1
        except Exception as ex:
            print("Could not open ", fileName)
            print("  Actual exception error message is:")
            print("  "+str(ex))
        return fileName


def readFile(fileName):
    inFile = open(fileName, "r")
    count = 1
    for lineOfText in inFile:
        print(count,": ",lineOfText,end="")
        count = count + 1
        print("   >>", wordCount(lineOfText), "words")
    return lineOfText


def wordCount(sentence):
    wordCount=0
    sentence=sentence.strip( )
    for i in range (0, len(sentence)):
        if (sentence[i]==" "):
            wordCount=wordCount+1
    if (len(sentence)>0):
        wordCount=wordCount+1
        return wordCount


def wordAverage(a,b):
    average = a/b
    print("The average words per lines are",average)


def minWords(x,y,z):
    if x<=y and x<=z:
        print("Least words in a line:", x)
    elif y<=x and y<=z:
        print("Least words in a line:", y)
    else:
        print("Least words in a line:", z)


def maxWords(x,y,z):
    if x>=y and x>=z:
        print("Most words in a line:", x)
        return x
    elif y>=x and y>=z:
        print("Most words in a line:", y)
        return y
    else:
        print("Most words in a line:", z)
        return z


def totalWords(x,y,z):
    total=x+y+z
    print("Total words in input: ", total)


def totalLines(fileName):
    inFile = open(fileName, "r")
    count = 1
    for lineOfText in inFile:
        count = count + 1
    inFile.close()
    return count
```

This is my main. I am trying to get x to be the first input, y to be the next, and z to be my last.

```
#main

print("Welcome to file analysis")

fileName=fileVerify()
sent=readFile(fileName)

x=wordCount(sent)
y=wordCount(sent)
z=wordCount(sent)

print("\nAnalysis")
print("===========")

minWords(x,y,z)
a=maxWords(x,y,z)
b=totalLines(fileName)
wordAverage(a, b)
totalWords(x,y,z)
```

Comment: Why are you calculating the same `wordCount(sent)` three times? And `readFile` only returns the last line because it's the only one you saved. You go through the previous ones, but don't do anything with them.

Comment: @TimCastelijns - I think you mean `len(sentence.strip().split())`, or perhaps `sentence.count(' ')` (if a single space is the guaranteed whitespace, which I hope it is, given the OP's algorithm).

Comment: @TigerharkT3 - how would I save the previous ones?

Comment: You might want to check the [official tutorial's section on the `list` type](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/introduction.html#lists). That whole tutorial is worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

There's a potentially easier way to count words. Rather than counting the number of spaces in your sentence, you could create a list based upon splitting the sentence, like so:

```
    >>> sentence = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."
    >>> splitSentence = sentence.split()
    >>> splitSentence
    ['The', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumped', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog.']
    >>> len(splitSentence)
    9
```

.split() is a string method that creates a list from the original string by splitting up the string wherever it finds a space (by default) or a substring of your choice (for example, .split(",") would split on commas). You can test the subsequent list for its length very easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
words = len(sentence.split())
```

`words` will be the number of words in the string `sentence`.